# Checkboxes on Show Hide Div

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, hide, show

I have a div that appears when the user clicks on the form and disappear when the user clicks elsewhere. This works fine. The problem is, there are some checkboxes on this particular div.  And they dont work when I use this jquery script to show/hide the div. Can someone tell me what I should do? Thank you.
Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
var divVisible=false;
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //divVisible=true;
      // user clicks on report this button
       $(".box").click(function() {

      // confirmation fades in
         divVisible=true;
          $("#mydiv").fadeIn("fast"),

          // Prevent events from getting pass #searchappear
          $("#mydiv").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
          });return false;
       });

      $(document.body).click(function () {
        //$("body").click(function(){
            // hide the share-box if clicked anywhere aside from the box itself
        //console.log(divVisible);
            if(divVisible==true){
            $("#mydiv").fadeOut().removeClass("active");
             divVisible=false; 
            }
          });
      });
      //});

</script>
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the html looks like. Can you post an excerpt of it?

Comment: <div id="mydiv">
 <form>
<div id="abc"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />ABC</div>
<div id="def"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />DEF</div>
<div id="hij"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />HIJ</div>
<div id="klm"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" />KLM</div>
</form>
</div>

I had put the checkboxes in divs because I have to use them with this background image and I had too much trouble getting them in the right position using any other method.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the return false from the #mydiv click, it's preventing the click on the checkbox from working.